# Why does Textual have a "party" theme icon for no obvious reason?

Tags: macos, textual

I just noticed that my IRC client, [Textual](http://www.codeux.com/textual/), has a different icon than usual. Why?

There are no notifications in the app that could explain this. It's not my birthday or anyone's I know either.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today, July 23rd, is Textual's birthday, and it changes its icon for the day. From the [source code](https://github.com/Codeux/Textual/blob/d6be278519a6a697057b6c72942c545aa6ce26b3/Classes/Views/TVCDockIcon.m#L73):

> The first public commit of Textual occured on July, 23, 2010. **This is the day that we consider the birthday of the application.**

Source code excerpt showing the condition for the different icon:

```
/* THIS IS A SECRET!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

 Birthday icon designed by Alex Sørlie Glomsaas. */

NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *breakdownInfo = [sysCalendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

/* The first public commit of Textual occured on July, 23, 2010. This is the day
 that we consider the birthday of the application. */
if ([breakdownInfo month] == 7 && [breakdownInfo day] == 23) {
    return [NSImage imageNamed:@"birthdayIcon"];
} else {
    return [NSImage imageNamed:@"NSApplicationIcon"];
}
```